# what is uniform random phase in texture synthesis and how to use it?

Tags: image-processing, textures

can someone help me to understand these points, how to define the random uniform phase matrix using these points [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubLYi.png written in this paper https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01553841v2/document for texture synthesis1